# How to loop HashMap style in the View in SWIFTUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
var someProtocol = [SurveyItems : [Surveys]]()

sectionLabels.forEach{ a in
    var finalSurveys = [Surveys]()
    surveys.forEach{ b in
        if a.groupHeader == b.group_survey {
            finalSurveys.append(b)
        }
        someProtocol[a] = finalSurveys
    }
}
```

I wanted to use that someProtocol to dynamically display the label section and the surveys under that section.

```
for (Surveys, SurveyItems) in someProtocol {
    Text(Surveys.sectionTitle)
    for survey in SurveyItems {
        Text(survey.label)
    }
}
```

I tried ViewBuider but getting some error.

Comment: You need “ForEach” not “for in”

Comment: What is "some error?" It looks like you've just accidentally used `for...in` when you meant `ForEach`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To loop and display your `someProtocol` dictionary in a View, try this example code:
Adjust the code for your own purpose. Note that in a SwiftUI View you need to use a `ForEach` not the "normal" swift `for x in ...` to loop over a sequence.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var someProtocol = [SurveyItems : [Surveys]]()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(Array(someProtocol.keys), id: \.self) { key in
            VStack {
                if let surveys = someProtocol[key] {
                    Text(key.title).foregroundColor(.red)
                    ForEach(surveys, id: \.self) { survey in
                        Text("survey \(survey.label)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            // for testing
            someProtocol[SurveyItems(id: "1", number: 1, title: "title-1")] = [Surveys(id: "s1", label: "label-1"), Surveys(id: "s2", label: "label-2")]
            someProtocol[SurveyItems(id: "2", number: 2, title: "title-2")] = [Surveys(id: "s3", label: "label-3")]
        }
    }

}

struct SurveyItems: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: String
    let number: Int
    var title: String
}

struct Surveys: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: String
    let label: String
}
```